# Is it required to initialize context twice in Android ?

Tags: android, android-context

I have seen in many places android context is initialized twice ? Why is it required ?

For Example :

```
Context context;
context = null;
```

again they will initialize it to some values in onCreate, onReceive or in some other Method

```
context = myContext;
```

If anyway we have to initialize it to value, why then initializing it to null ?

Anything specific to Android ?

Thanks

Comment: In Java, if you define a variable in a method, say, Context context and then assign this variable a context you pass into that method, like context = myContext, then you must initialize your initial context variable. This do not yield global variables, because they does not have to be initialized

Comment: @user1223035 where did you see it.post code.

Comment: @Mocialov - Do you mean then we require all three ?

Comment: @user1223035 no, can also be: `Context context = null; context ´myContext`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. 
>   If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it 
>   a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result
>   in a compile-time error.

Example:

```
someMethod(Context myContext){
  Context context;
  context = null; //Have to be done to avoid compile-time error

  context = myContext;
}
```

Example 2:

```
private Context context;

someMethod(Context myContext){
  context = myContext;  //No initialization required, because context variable is not local
}
```

---

To Answer your question:

1. We are initializing variable to **null** to keep consistency intact
2. No, this is not Android specific, but rather Java specific

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this is done of old habits only. Java should by default set field object references to `null`. I doubt Android handle this differently.

Setting them to null might even result in duplicate operations on byte code level. For further information refer to [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=14) page.